# Where should I store a bunch of strings I intend on using in a single feature (for a short amount of time)?

Tags: python, django, database, design-patterns

I have a (relatively) big and complex (Django) app with multiple database tables.

Now, I'm building the landing page of a new feature that includes a section where are displayed 3 random sentences from a collection of 10 predefined strings.

I want to be able to update and change these strings without having to rebuild and redeploy the app each time.

Should I create another table in the database just to store this data or are there other ways to do it (properly)?

Answer (score 1):

If they are strings that you want to randomize every time the page is rendered, you can use a context processor.

```py
import random


SENTENCES = (
    'Lorem ipsum...',
    'The first rule of Fight Club...',
    'Would you look at that?',
    'Just look at it!',
)

def get_landing_page_sentences() -> list:
    return random.sample(SENTENCES, 3)

def app_context(request) -> dict:
    return {
        'landing_page_sentences': get_landing_page_sentences()
    }
```

If you want to change the sentence string themselves at runtime, then I would use a simple database model plus a context processor. Tables are cheap. I don't think it's necessary to introduce another mechanism or persistence layer.

```py
from django.db import models


class LandingPageSentence(models.Model):
    sentence = models.CharField(max_length=255)

def app_context(request) -> dict:
    return {
        'landing_page_sentences': LandingPageSentence.objects.order_by('?')[:3]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However my question is not really about **how to choose** the sentences to display, but rather about **where to store** them.  •  According to your examples, you suggest I either 1) hardcode the text in the app itself, or 2) use the database.  •  But 1) makes it impossible to update the copy without redeploying the app, and 2) seems like an overkill for storing just 10 sentences.  •  On the other hand I'm not sure I'm using the right mental frame while trying to find the appropriate approach.

Comment: I am indeed suggesting #2. Using the database isn't overkill - it's literally what a database is made for: storing structured data of a _variable_ number of records. A table doesn't have to be a certain size to make it "worth storing in the database". Plus, data tends to grow. What if you want 100 random sentences, or 1000? What if you want to ensure no duplicated sentence fragments with a unique index? The mental frame is simply "let data be data".